# How can optimize below code for counting repeat of each elements in nested of nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, optimization

The code I wrote counts the frequency of each element in a nested list.
I have a lot of repeated code. How can I optimize it?
I don't want to use built-in function or lib.

**Input**:

```
items = [10, "ninety nine", [99, 250, [90, "fifty"], 4.5, [50, 80], 90, "ninety nine"], ["fifty"]]
```

**Output**:

```
{10: 1, 'ninety nine': 2, 99: 1, 250: 1, 90: 2, 'fifty': 2, 4.5: 1, 50: 1, 80: 1}
```

**Code**:

```py
items = [10, "ninety nine", [99, 250, [90, "fifty"], 4.5, [50, 80], 90, "ninety nine"], ["fifty"]]

dict1 = dict()


for i in items:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        for j in i:
            if isinstance(j, list):
                for k in j:
                    if k not in dict1:
                        dict1[k] = 1
                    else:
                        dict1[k] += 1
            else:
                if j in dict1:
                    dict1[j] += 1
                else:
                    dict1[j] = 1

    else:
        if i in dict1:
            dict1[i] += 1
        else:
            dict1[i] = 1


print(dict1)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion to *flatten* the list and then count specific items:

```py
items = [
    10,
    "ninety nine",
    [99, 250, [90, "fifty"], 4.5, [50, 80], 90, "ninety nine"],
    ["fifty"],
]


def get_items(v):
    if isinstance(v, list):
        for i in v:
            yield from get_items(i)
    else:
        yield v


cnt = {}
for i in get_items(items):
    cnt[i] = cnt.get(i, 0) + 1

print(cnt)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    10: 1,
    "ninety nine": 2,
    99: 1,
    250: 1,
    90: 2,
    "fifty": 2,
    4.5: 1,
    50: 1,
    80: 1,
}
```